# How to restore/validate sliced & shuffled image?

Tags: python, image-processing

First of all I got an image that is sliced into different pieces and shuffled, like the following image:

[image]

I am not sure how the image got restored, like the following:

[image]

Or are there any way to validate the output image, if I could brute-force to generate all kinds of combination. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly no fool-proof way of doing that, but you could calculate some probability of being correct for all possible combinations.

For each edge in the image, calculate the color difference between the neighboring pixels and sum up these differences. The combination with the smallest sum of differences is probably the right one.

This will work quite well with images such as the provided one, it will not work good if the images do have sharp borders at the edges or a lot of similar colors in general. So if the images are technical drawings or diagrams, you're probably lost.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I really hope I could find something similar in Github that I can make use of.

Comment: @Winston I've made a recommendation for an algorithm, recommendations for implementations are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. I didn't mean you need to work on the algorithm (I said I hope I could find). But if there are some existing tool/code that could find the most probable image based on the group of images.